# Log4j logs show on console without log4j.properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, log4j

I have been working on a Spring Boot project using Maven. I need to write logs for system activity. I have been following this example for log4j [Example](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/)

This is the code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloExample{

        final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloExample.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            HelloExample obj = new HelloExample();
            obj.runMe("mkyong");

        }

        private void runMe(String parameter){

            if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                logger.debug("This is debug : " + parameter);
            }

            if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
                logger.info("This is info : " + parameter);
            }

            logger.warn("This is warn : " + parameter);
            logger.error("This is error : " + parameter);
            logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + parameter);

        }

    }
```

I face 2 issues:
1. The main compiles, runs & gives the following output as in the image without having the log4j.properties
[image]

2. Even after having the log4j.properties file in the resources folder, the logs are not stored to the log file.

The file is created if the application is not springboot. I don't understand where I am going wrong. 
P.S: I am a beginner in Java & Spring.

Comment: Perhaps if you read the [Spring Boot **documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html), you would learn why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spring boot with log4j, you need to use spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency.Please follow the below link for the solution.

https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-log4j-2-example/

Comment: Thanks. I now understand that because of the default logging in SpringBoot, the log4j.properties file is not read. I had to disable default logging in SpringBoot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html). This explains how logging works in a Spring boot application.

The paragraph about [file output](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output) shows how you can write logs into specific files.